# Does fuzzy logic really improve simple machine learning algorithms?

Tags: data-structures, machine-learning, computer-science, fuzzy-logic

I'm reading about fuzzy logic and I just don't see how it would possibly improve machine learning algorithms in most instances (which it seems to be applied to relatively often).

Take for example, k nearest neighbors.  If you have a bunch a bunch of attributes like `color: [red,blue,green,orange], temperature: [real number], shape: [round, square, triangle]`, you can't really fuzzify any of these except for the real numbered attribute (please correct me if I'm wrong), and I don't see how this can improve anything more than bucketing things together.

How can machine fuzzy logic be used to improve machine learning?  The toy examples you'll find on most websites don't seem to be all that applicable, most of the time.

Comment: This is a question of semantics. Red/blue/green/orange are potentially "fuzzy" terms if you're not talking about their literal RGB values. Similarly for the terms round/square/triangle.

Answer (score 7):

Fuzzy logic is advisable when the variables have a natural shape interpretation. For example, [very few, few, many, very many] have a nice overlapping trapezoid interpretation of values.

Variables like color might not. Fuzzy variables denote degree of membership, that's when they become useful.

Regarding machine learning, it depends on what stage of the algorithm you want to apply fuzzy logic. It would be better applied in my opinion after the clusters are found (using traditional learning techniques) to determining the degree of membership of a certain point in the search space on each cluster, but that doesn't improve learning per see, but classification after learning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish in the example you give (shapes, colors, etc.).  Fuzzy logic has been used successfully with machine learning, but personally I think it is probably more often useful in constructing policies.  Rather than go on about it, I refer you to an article I published in the Mar/Apr-2002 issue of "PC AI" magazine, which hopefully makes the idea clear:

[Putting Fuzzy Logic to Work: An Introduction to Fuzzy Rules](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2163280/Putting-Fuzzy-Logic-to-Work#scribd)

Answer (score 0):

[round, square, triangle] are mostly ideal categories, which exist primarily in geometry (i.e. in theory). In real world, some shapes might be almost square or more or less round (circular shape). There are many nuances of red, and some colors are closer to some others (ask a woman to explain turquoise, for example). Hence, also abstract categories and some specific values are useful as references, in real world the objects or values are not necessarily equals to these ones.

Fuzzy membership allow you to measure how far are some specific objects from some ideal. Using this measure lets one to avoid "no, it's not circular" (which might lead to information loss) and make use of the measure the given object is (not) circular.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, fuzzy logic is not a practically viable approach to anything unless you are building a purpose build fuzzified controller or some rule based structure like for compliance/policies. Although, fuzzy implies dealing with everything between and including 0 and 1. It, however, I find is a bit flawed when you approach more complicated problems where you need to apply fuzzy logic aspects in 3 dimensional spaces. You can still approach multivariate without having to look at fuzzy logic. Unfortunately, for me having studied fuzzy logic I found myself disagreeing with the principles approached in fuzzy sets in large dimensional spaces it seems infeasible, unpractical, and not very logically sound. The natural language base that you would be applying in your fuzzy set solution will also be very adhoc what exactly is [very,few, many] this is all what you define in your application. 
Alot, of machine learning aspects you will find that you don't even have to go so far as to build natural language underpinnings into your model. In fact, you will find you can achieve even better results without having to apply fuzzy logic into any aspect of your model.

Answer (score 0):

just too irritate you a bit by **forcibly adding fuzziness** to this. if *instead of the "shape" attribute you had a "number of sides" attribute* which would have been further divided into *"less", "medium", "many" and "uncountable"*. the square could have been a part of "less" and "medium" both given the appropriate membership function. in place of the *"color" attribute, if you had "red" attribute*, then using the RGB code, a membership function could have been made. so as my experience in data mining says, **every method can be applied to every dataset, what works, works.**

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't one just convert discrete sets into continuous ones and get the same effects as fuzziness, while being able to use all the techniques of probability theory?

For instance size ['small', 'medium', 'big'] ==> [0,1]